# processing a tuple in lambda expression in list comprehensions

Tags: python, lambda, list-comprehension

I am learning python and was just fiddling with the lambda expressions and list comprehensions when I realized that:

`>>> list(map(lambda x: x*x, [1,2]))`

outputs `>>> 1,4` but

`>>> list(map(lambda (x): x*x, [1,2]))`
shows an error pointing at parenthesis around `x`

It appears that the lambda expression cannot have a parenthesis around its parameters list. (Checked in python 3.x)

I now want to ask that if I cannot add a parenthesis around the parameters in the lambda expression, then how can I process a tuple using a map and a lambda expression. for eg:

```
>>> records = [('bob', 35, 'manager'), ('sue', 40, 'developer')]
>>> list(map((lambda (name, age, job): age), records))
```

this statement shows a syntax error indicating the parenthesis before the `name` parameter. I then tried an expression without the parenthesis:

`>>> list(map((lambda name, age, job: age), records))`

But this statement also shows an error saying that lambda expression needs 3 arguments but only 1 was provided.

I get that the map function is pulling out an entire record tuple from `records` list and passing it to the lambda function, and the `lambda function` is taking this entire tuple record as an argument to the  `name` parameter.

I want to know, How can I process a tuple in a lambda expression. Also please tell me why is it written so in the book *(Learning python by Mark Lutz)* that this works? Is it for python 2.x. I am new to python. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Apparently, it works on my system which has 2.7 environment so book is not completely wrong

Comment: An other way of doing the same: `list(map(lambda x: x[1], records))`.

Comment: @mad_ Thanks. I thought so for version 2.7 but had no means of checking the same. you cleared my doubt. I appreciate it. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The syntax you are attempting works in Python 2.x. It won't work in Python 3.

In Python 3, you can use positional indexing:

```
from operator import itemgetter

records = [('bob', 35, 'manager'), ('sue', 40, 'developer')]

ages1 = list(map(lambda x: x[1], records))   # [35, 40]
ages2 = list(map(itemgetter(1), records))    # [35, 40]
```

Better (more efficient, more readable) is to abandon `lambda` altogether. You can use a list comprehension with sequence unpacking:

```
ages3 = [age for _, age, _ in records]       # [35, 40]
```

You can even use `zip` if you don't mind a `tuple`:

```
_, ages4, _ = zip(*records)                  # (35, 40)
```

For a cleaner version of the last solution, you can use `itertools.islice`:

```
from itertools import islice

ages5 = next(islice(zip(*records), 1, 2))    # (35, 40)
```

Comment: Or just `ages3 = [age for _, age, _ in records]`.

Comment: @Austin, Agreed :). I left the other identifiers there for clarity. But in terms of design you're right, unused variables don't need to be named.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the special unpacking syntax with `lambda`s in Python2 only. However, you can use `itertools.starmap` to accomplish the unpacking of each item in `records` as it is passed to the function under the hood in Python3:

```
import itertools
records = [('bob', 35, 'manager'), ('sue', 40, 'developer')]
print(list(itertools.starmap(lambda name, age, job: age, records)))
```

Output:

```
[35, 40]
```

Comment: You can avoid enclosing the lambda in parenthesis

Comment: @Pynchia Yes, the parenthesis were copied from the OP's code.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just

```
list(map((lambda x:x[1]), records))
```